# Lowercasing certain words with awk

Tags: awk

Goal: Only lowercase words in field 1 which meet "^[A-Z][a-z]+$". Fields are separated by tab.

Input:

```
Agne  XXX
Agn_Ball  YYY
```

Output:

```
agne  XXX
Agne_Ball  YYY
```

Code:

```
awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN {OFS='\t'} $1 ~ /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/ {print tolower($1),$2}1' < test.tmp > test.tmp2
```

However, the result is:

```
agne XXX
Agne  XXX
Agne_Ball  YYY
```

So how to modify the command to get the result.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/^([A-Z][a-z]+\t)/\l$1/'`

Comment: @melpomene Thanks a lot! It works. I feel necessary to learn perl now.

Answer (score 3):

You were pretty close, you need to use `next` in your condition block to avoid 2 times printing. Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[A-Za-z]+$/{$1=tolower($1)} 1' Input_file
```

OR as per jas's suggestion in comments adding following too here.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[A-Z][a-z]+$/{$1=tolower($1)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1 == "Agne" {print tolower($1),$2}sub(/Agn_/,"Agne_")' OFS="\t" file

agne    XXX
Agne_Ball  YYY
```

Comment: This will be very specific to OP's example. I believe that OP given only an example of this string, OP wants to do this for all matching lines.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.